# Getting background-image URL from numbered elements

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want, via jQuery, to get the background-image url, from the element i'm clicking on. The problem is that the divs are numbered, since I needed a way to have many different images. This is how they are numbered:

```html
<div id="photoBackground photo1"></div>
<div id="photoBackground photo2"></div>
<div id="photoBackground photo3"></div>
<div id="photoBackground photo4"></div>
etc etc
```

I have this is jQuery right now:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.photoBackground').click(function () {
    var image = $(this).css('background-image');
    // remove "url(" and ")" to get the url
    image = image.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
    $("#lightbox").css('background-image','url(' + image + ')');
})
});
```

How do I make it read from the numbered ids? Eg. photo1, photo2 etc?

Thanks!

- Magnus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CSS an ID should be unique. Make .photobackground a class and then do photo1, photo2, etc as the id. Then do the on click function

```
$('.photoBackground').on('click',function () {
var idIClickedOn = '#' + $(this).attr('id'); //this will give you the actual id of the element
var image = $(idIClickedOn ).css('background-image');
// remove "url(" and ")" to get the url
image = image.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
$("#lightbox").css('background-image','url(' + image + ')');
})
```

Answer (score 1):

An element ID can't have a space in it.

Since your jQuery selector is already looking for a class `photoBackground` change the html to following structure:

```
<div id="photo4" class="photoBackground"></div>
```

Then within click handler `this.id` will be id of element that was clicked

```
$('.photoBackground').click(function () {
     var id = this.id;
     // do something with id and background


});
```

ID's must be unique, but class is used to group common elements with common class names

Comment: Just for your knowledge, the background image is attached to photo'number'. I will gladly try this. :)